# Search removing comma using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, search, str-replace

I want to search a text that contains comma in database, but, there is not comma in the reference.

For example. In database I have the following value:
"Development of computer programs, including electronic games"

So, I try to search the data using the following string as reference:
"development of computer programs including electronic games"

**NOTE** that the only difference is that in database I have a comma in the text, but, in my reference for search, I have not.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult>Index(string nomeServico)
{
  using (MyDB db = new MyDB())
  {
    // 1st We receive the following string:"development-of-computer-programs-including-electronic-games"
    // but we remove all "-" characters 
    string serNome = nomeServico.RemoveCaractere("-", " ");

    // we search the service that contains (in the SerName field) the value equal to the parameter of the Action.
    Servicos servico = db.Servicos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SerNome.ToLower().Equals(serNome, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
  }
}
```

The problem is that, in the database, the data contains comma, and in the search value, don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code you are replacing "-" with "" and that too in your search string. But as per your requirement you need to change "," with "" for your DB entry.

Try doing something like this:

```
string serNome = nomeServico.ToLower();
Servicos servico = db.Servicos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SerNome.Replace(",","").ToLower() == serNome);
```

Comment: But, the .Replace replaces only the first instance. If I have 3 commas, the .Replace will remove only the first one.

Comment: @Dan Are you sure about that?? I think replace replaces all matching elements. Did you try it?